# The product topological space of two finite closed topologies is not finite closed.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $X_1, X_2$ be infite sets and $\tau_1$and $\tau_2$ the finite closed topologies on $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.
>   Show that the product topology $\tau$ on $X_1\times X_2$ is not the finite closed topology.

As $X_1$ is infite then if $\{x\}\in X$ then $X_1\setminus\{x\}\in\tau_1$.
Then $\{x\}\times X_2$ is by definition an open set in the product topology space however its complement is $\{x\}\times X_2$ is not finite as $X_2$ is infinite contradicting the fact $\{x\}\times X_2$ is closed. Therefore $\{x\}\times X_2$ is not open. Then the product topology cannot be the finite closed topology.

**Questions**:

Is this proof right? If not why not? Which are the alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x\} \times X_2$ is not open, but it *is* closed. Since it is infinite, we are done.